# Syntax error or access violation: 1055

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Estoy tratando de hacer este query en laravel

```
public function index(){
    $searchQuery = request()->input('q');
    if( $searchQuery == null ) return redirect()->route('wellcomer');
    
    $terms = $this->encode( $searchQuery );
    $search = DB::table('search_terms')
        ->select('products.*', 'search_terms.product_id', 'search_terms.term')
        ->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'search_terms.product_id');

    $search = $search->whereRaw('search_terms.term like "%?%"', [$terms]);
    
    collect( explode(' ', $terms) )->each(function($term) use ($search){
        $search->orWhereRaw('search_terms.term like "%?%"', [$term]);
    });

    $search->groupBy('search_terms.product_id');

    return view('search.index', [
        'products' => $search->inRandomOrder()->get(),
        'searchQuery' => $searchQuery,
    ]);
}
```

pero me arroja este error:

```
[2020-09-01 07:28:11] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'tiend252_app.products.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `products`.*, `search_terms`.`product_id`, `search_terms`.`term` from `search_terms` inner join `products` on `products`.`id` = `search_terms`.`product_id` where search_terms.term like "%65%" or search_terms.term like "%65%" group by `search_terms`.`product_id` order by RAND()) {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 42000): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'tiend252_app.products.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `products`.*, `search_terms`.`product_id`, `search_terms`.`term` from `search_terms` inner join `products` on `products`.`id` = `search_terms`.`product_id` where search_terms.term like \"%65%\" or search_terms.term like \"%65%\" group by `search_terms`.`product_id` order by RAND()) at /home/tiend252/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671)
[stacktrace]
```

el metodo `encode()`, es un algoritmo de metaphone que desarrolle, por eso verán algo como `"%65%"` en el where.

lo peor del caso, es que ejecuto el SQL en phpMyAdmin y funciona bien.

```
select `products`.*, `search_terms`.`product_id`, `search_terms`.`term` from `search_terms` inner join `products` on `products`.`id` = `search_terms`.`product_id` where search_terms.term like "%65%" or search_terms.term like "%65%" group by `search_terms`.`product_id` order by RAND()
```

uso el metodo `whereRaw` porque sin el, en el SQL aparecia el valor del where sin comillas. asi:

```
where like %65%
```

llegué a pensar que eso solucionaría mi error, pero no.

los campos de las tablas son:

products:

`id | title | description | slug | image | bs_price | usd_price | stock | store_id | created_at updated_at`

search_terms:

`id | product_id    | term | created_at | updated_at`

Answer (score 1):

Tu error radica en que tú `select` tiene un número de columnas elegidas que no empata con las columnas por las cuales estás agrupando.

Laravel viene configurado<sup>1</sup> con un modo estricto para NO permitir estás inconsistencias en consulta SQL, por eso ahí no funciona y en tu MySQL/MariaDB si por qué en estos dos últimos debes [configurar el modo estricto.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

SOLUCIÓN:

Agrupa por los mismos elementos de tu `select` así

```
select('columna1', 'columna2', 'columnaN')
....
groupBy('columna1', 'columna2', 'columnaN')
```

**Referencia**

- [Puedes revisar mas aquí](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/database.php#L59)

Comment: Si ves en mi select está `search_terms.product_id` y estoy agrupando por `search_terms.product_id`

Comment: si @Franklin'jGil'z pero en tu select tienes mas columnas elegidas, por eso te propongo que las agregues todas por que por ahi va el fallo

Comment: Voy a tratar de seleccionar bien los campos entonces y renombrarlos. el otro problema es que en local funciona.. :/